# Cannot get the correct files in the folder using SQL xp_smdshell command

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, command-line

I have files in my computer's folder with following names:

```
XXX.IN.txt
YYY.TEST.NUM.txt
ABC.AA.Z100.X.E999567777.Y001.txt
ABC.AA.Z100.X.E999568888.Y002.txt
ABC.AA.Z100.X.E999568888.Y003.txt
```

I want to write a SQL statement that would insert files that have the above described structure into a table, so I can later on write some logic on them.

I already used the command line statement inside of my stored proc to check if files exist:

```
EXEC master.dbo.xp_fileexist @fullPath, @exist OUTPUT
SET @exist = CAST(@exist AS BIT)
```

Now, I need to find certain files containing string in their names. I have the statement to do that:

```
DECLARE @cmdLine VARCHAR(200)
DECLARE @fullPath VARCHAR(900) = '\\my_network_path\MyDir\'
DECLARE @filter VARCHAR(100) = 'ABC.AA.Z100.X.*.txt'

SET @cmdLine = 'dir "' + @fullPath + '"' 
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmdLine
```

Above command should give me the following files:

```
ABC.AA.Z100.X.E999567777.Y001.txt
ABC.AA.Z100.X.E999568888.Y002.txt
ABC.AA.Z100.X.E999568888.Y003.txt

CREATE TABLE #FileDetails
(
    data VARCHAR(MAX)
)
INSERT #FileDetails(data) EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmdLine
```

But it lists all the `.txt` files in the folder

How would I do list only those files that I need

Comment: Why not the names of all the tables into the Into a temp table then use T-SQL to remove whatever you don't need. Unless I'm missing something, this is a no-brainer.

Comment: Actually, that's what I'm doing now

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the @cmdline should be set higher than @fullpath since it's supposed to fit all of it in the end.

Second of all, unless I am looking at it wrong or you didn't correct it here, the @filter variable isn't being used, so it would show every file regardless of extension.

My Code:

```
DECLARE @cmdLine VARCHAR(2000)
DECLARE @fullPath VARCHAR(1000) = '\\my_network_path\MyDir\'
DECLARE @filter VARCHAR(100) = 'ABC.AA.Z100.X.*.txt'

SET @cmdLine = 'dir "' + @fullPath + @filter + '"' 
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmdLine
```

My Output (keep in mind I created a Test.txt in the same folder):

```
10-10-2017  12:17                 0 ABC.AA.Z100.X.Y001.txt
10-10-2017  12:18                 0 ABC.AA.Z100.X.Y002.txt
10-10-2017  12:18                 0 ABC.AA.Z100.X.Y003.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this with either a CLR proc or an SSIS Script that uses the FileSystemObject to iterate through the files, filter for the ones you want and build a SQL String and execute it.

I don't know any way to do what you want with just straight TSQL.